# How do you create a string of integers with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm teaching myself jQuery. My first project is to build a simple dialpad. After scrapping through the docs I can't seem to find what I'm looking for so I'm turning to here. I want to be able to create a string of integers that will be the phone number to dial when user press button keys with a number value. I've found many examples online but I want to understand the logic. So far my code just print one value on the phone screen and it's not even the right number. I'm missing the point. How can I make this work?

This is what I have so far :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.numpad').click(function(){
    
        var number = $('.numpad').val();
    
    $('#phoneScreen').val(number);
    
    });
    
    
});
```

```css
.numpad{
    padding:1%;
    width:100%;
}
.hidpad{
   visibility:hidden;
}
.btn-call{
    margin-top:3%;
   margin-bottom:5%;
}
```

```html
 <!-- bootstrap css stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- bootstrap javascript, jquery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="table-bordered text-center col-md-4">
    <br>
    

  <div id="mydivheader"></h1></div>
<div class=""><input class="table-bordered form-control" type="text" id="phoneScreen" /></div><br>
<div class="row table-striped">
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="1"><span class="txt"> 1 </span><p class="hidpad">111</p></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="2"><span class="txt"> 2 </span><p>ABC</p></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="3"><span class="txt"> 3 </span><p>DEF</p></button>
</div>

</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="4"><span class="txt"> 4 </span><p>GHI</p></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="5"><span class="txt"> 5 </span><p>JKL</p></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="6"><span class="txt"> 6 </span><p>MNO</p></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="7"><span class="txt"> 7 </span><p>PQRS</p></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="8"><span class="txt"> 8 </span><p>TUV</p></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="9"><span class="txt"> 9 </span><p>WXYZ</p></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="*"><span class="txt"> * </span><p class="hidpad">***</p></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="+"><span class="txt"> 0 </span><p>+</p></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button class="numpad btn btn-default" value="#"><span class="txt"> # </span><p class="hidpad">###</p></button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row btn-call">
<div class="col-md-6">
<button id="makeCall" class="btn btn-success btn-dial"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/25/000000/ringer-volume.png"> Start Call</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<button  id="endCall" class="btn btn-danger btn-dial"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/25/000000/end-call.png"> End Call</button>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

My codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwVzWo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 $('.numpad').click(function(){
        //Use this to get the value of the button which triggered the event
        //$(this) refers to the button which triggered the event in this context
        //You were using class numpad which returned the value of the first element in
        //the collection, that's why you kept getting a value of 1
        var number = $(this).val();

    //On this line you want to append the newly pressed key to the existing value
    //Of the element with id phoneScreen
    $('#phoneScreen').val($('#phoneScreen').val() + number);


});
```

Comment: They were probably creating their answer as you posted yours, and didn't see the timestamp of the two answers. Fortunately, it's under your answer right now as 13 mins ago, and theirs is 9 minutes ago, so really, @NiMusco provided the duplicate.

Comment: Ryan, It looked otherwise to me few minutes ago, like mine was older (Maybe some client-side thing?). Now I see the same as you, so I just deleted mine. Downvote was for wrong .append() comment. Since you corrected it, now it's an upvote. Stay well!

Comment: @NiMusco You were completely right about the .append(), thanks. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` inside the call back function to refering the element being clicked instead $('.numpad'). With your code, the jQuery get the value of the first `$('.numpad')` element and update the  `$('#phoneScreen')` value. (this is why only the number 1 has show up)

Currently, your code is overwriting the display in phone screen. We want to concatenate this numbers, instead of adding. To do this, we get the phoneScreen value and concatenate with the number clicked.
Sometimes javascript calculate two numbers when we want to concatenate them, so we use `.toString()` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.numpad').click(function(){

        var number = $(this).val();
        var phoneScreen =  $('#phoneScreen').val();

        $('#phoneScreen').val( (phoneScreen + number).toString() );

    }); 
});
```

Look the code below. Makes the same thing, and no needs to import libs.

```
window.onload = function(){
  var numpads = document.querySelectorAll('.numpad');
  var phoneScreen = document.getElementById('phoneScreen');

  numpads.forEach( function(elem, index) {
     elem.addEventListener('click', function( evt ){
       var value = elem.value;
       phoneScreen.value += value;

     });
  });
}
```